# Display the contents of a .txt in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a batch file right now and I have everything done that I need but I'm stuck at one point. One of the programs I use spits out a log file and I have it place this file on the C:drive in a folder. What I want to do is have it read this .txt and spit that back into the batch file as an echo.

Comment: More information is needed... why not use the `TYPE` command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can put this in your batch file:

```
type C:\folder\test.txt
```

This will echo out the contents of test.txt.